# I get a warning from Gparted Partition Editor

Tags: gparted

I get a warning as the app starts up.

Libparted warning:
The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

What does it mean? 
Because of this warning, I didn't do anything with the app.

Comment: Does this message shows when trying to install from a Live USB?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article: [gparted block size warning](https://codeyarns.com/2017/02/04/gparted-block-size-warning/)

**WARNING:** the command shown at the link above will destroy all data on the given device - the same goes for the command below.

It does mention to the same warning message. When a USB stick was used to install Ubuntu, the creation of the booteable media could change the block size of the USB device.

The solution, according to the article author is to run the following command, replacing `<device_path>`, with your device path, for example `/dev/sdb`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=<device_path> bs=2048 count=1 # this will destroy all data on the given device
```

Comment: This comment pops up at #2 when searching "ask Ubuntu" for “physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512”. Your advice @GTRONICK and the referenced link  will delete all data on the given device and should not be given without a *BIG* warning sign. There are lots of noobs here, that will copy/paste stuff into the CLI without understanding what it does.